# better word for items on a menu

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a better word or phrase for an item on a menu than "menu item"?  I'm talking about restaurant menus, not user interface menus.  "Menu item" is so dry...

"Restaurant dishes" doesn't work very well, because some of the things on a typical menu aren't dishes (cocktails for example).

Comment: How will this be used? And in what circumstance is *menu item* invalid for the audience?

Comment: Would the word "options" suit better?

Comment: Cocktails, Appetizers, entrees, main course, desserts chicken, pasta, seafood, salad. House Specials. Soup de jour, pomme frite combos.... All are 'menu items'

Comment: Food and drinks?

Comment: I'm designing software, and I need to express this concept in documentation and in the user interface.  _Menu item_ isn't too bad, but I was hoping for something a little more flavorful.  Also, in software, one runs the risk that _menu item_ will be interpreted to mean something relating to the interface of the software itself.

Comment: *Item* is the correct and recognized term for the individual elements of a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a term that will fit any section on the menu - entrées, fowl, pasta, soups, desserts, beverages, etc - then it's got to be **item**, **listing** or 
**choice**

> - item - "a thing or unit, esp included in a list or collection" [The Free Dicitonary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/item)
> - listing - "something that is listed" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/listing)
> - choice - "Other choices on the menu looked equally tempting." [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/listing)

Comment: *Choice* is what most people in the US would use in this context, I think. Another alternative for your list could be *entry*.

Comment: These are not bad, but they are lacking the idea that it's a restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the client and the use.  If its restaurant industry people using it, you'll be fine with something like "Food & Beverages".

If its consumer facing, it depends on the brand image the client wants to project - what you choose needs to fit their brand.  "Cuisine and Libations" wouldn't work with McDonalds but could be a perfect fit for the new hipster joint in the trendy part of town.

Unless its set in stone once you create it, keep it simple - Food and Drinks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use a cliche?
Print something like 'Here is what we can do for you..." with italic or handwritten font.

Although, Centaurus suggested "Choice" and it's very good.